# jquery working on development site but not production site window.location

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple script that determines whether we are at the base URL or not and loads different content based on location. The conditionals match in both dev and production, yet in production its failing the conditional?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myurl = '<!-- TMPL_VAR base_url -->'; /*returns http://instance_name.dev.domain.com/ */
    var currenturl = window.location; 
    alert(currenturl); /*returns http://instance_name.dev.domain.com/ */
    if(myurl == currenturl) {
        $( "#logo" ).load( "/static/carousel.html" );
    }
    else {
        $( "#logo" ).append( '<div class="logo visible-desktop visible-tablet"><img src="/static/images/logo.png" alt="A.A. Green Realty, Inc." /><h3>Real Estate | Real Experts | Real Results</h3></div>' );
    }    
});
</script>
```

console output:

```
> http://terricookson.dev.activemls.com/
> terricookson.dev.activemls.com/:893 LocationancestorOrigins:
> DOMStringListassign: function () { [native code] }hash: ""host:
> "terricookson.dev.activemls.com"hostname:
> "terricookson.dev.activemls.com"href:
> "http://terricookson.dev.activemls.com/"origin:
> "http://terricookson.dev.activemls.com"pathname: "/"port: ""protocol:
> "http:"reload: function reload() { [native code] }arguments:
> nullcaller: nulllength: 0name: "reload"__proto__: function Empty()
> {}apply: function apply() { [native code] }arguments: nullbind:
> function bind() { [native code] }call: function call() { [native code]
> }caller: nullconstructor: function Function() { [native code] }length:
> 0name: "Empty"toString: function toString() { [native code]
> }__proto__: Object<function scope><function scope>replace: function ()
> { [native code] }search: ""toString: function toString() { [native
> code] }valueOf: function valueOf() { [native code] }__proto__:
> Location
```

Comment: Do they really match? `console.log(escape(myurl)); console.log(escape(currenturl));`

Comment: I bet it's like a space on the end or difference in case or something.

Comment: @epascarello i added the console output to my OP

Comment: does `TMPL_VAR base_url` match in both environments?  It would be more useful if you so us the rendered source. Where is your console logging taking place? Adding a console log is fine and all, but not without understanding where things are being logged.

Comment: to those who down voted this, could you kindly explain why?

Comment: You really should be uisng `window.location.href` if you want the full URL.

Comment: @epascarello i added window.location.href. i think this has to do with the way our Apache is configured. although this is on our production server. console log now shows http://terricookson.com/ terricookson.prod.activemls.com/ & http://terricookson.prod.activemls.com/ this is due to the fact that the <!-- TMPL_VAR base_url --> returns the primary hostname configured for the instance in the database and Apache config. Anyway to work around this so that I can just check to see if im at the damn base url in my conditional

Comment: this conflict will most likely resolve itself when the domain has been pointed it think?

Answer (score 1):

You could instead use this.

```
window.location.pathname === "/"
```